# Extend table width manually

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

Is there a way in which I could stretch the width of these tables? I do not need it to be necessarily the page's width.

I have read the forums saying I should change to `tabular*` and put `extracolsp{\fill}`, but everything lost its formatting once I have done that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\newcommand{\M}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}{c}}


\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estatísticas Descritivas - Distribuição por UF} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}l*{3}{S[table-format=2.2]}}
  \toprule

UF & {Controle (\%)} & {Tratado (\%)} & {Total (\%)} \\ 
  \midrule
MG & 16.06 & 12.09 & 15.30 \\ 
  SP & 11.20 & 16.62 & 12.23 \\ 
  BA & 8.39 & 9.17 & 8.54 \\ 
  RS & 8.38 & 5.93 & 7.91 \\ 
  PR & 6.72 & 6.41 & 6.66 \\ 
  GO & 4.33 & 4.01 & 4.27 \\ 
  SC & 3.97 & 4.85 & 4.14 \\ 
  PB & 4.44 & 2.02 & 3.98 \\ 
  MA & 4.06 & 3.54 & 3.96 \\ 
  PE & 3.91 & 3.21 & 3.78 \\ 
  CE & 3.84 & 3.41 & 3.76 \\ 
  PI & 3.87 & 2.94 & 3.69 \\ 
  PA & 2.62 & 4.51 & 2.98 \\ 
  RN & 2.76 & 3.08 & 2.82 \\ 
  MT & 2.38 & 2.53 & 2.41 \\ 
  RJ & 1.94 & 3.36 & 2.21 \\ 
  TO & 2.15 & 2.11 & 2.15 \\ 
  AL & 2.06 & 1.23 & 1.90 \\ 
  ES & 1.38 & 1.95 & 1.49 \\ 
  SE & 1.55 & 1.09 & 1.46 \\ 
  MS & 1.31 & 1.88 & 1.42 \\ 
  AM & 1.03 & 2.22 & 1.26 \\ 
  RO & 0.84 & 0.97 & 0.87 \\ 
  AC & 0.36 & 0.22 & 0.33 \\ 
  AP & 0.25 & 0.33 & 0.27 \\ 
  RR & 0.19 & 0.29 & 0.21 \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "everything lost its formatting". Really everything, including the material outside the `tabular*` env. Please be specific.

Comment: Arthur, you forgot `\begin{document` / `\end{document}` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{16pt}` right before `\begin{tabular}`. Of course, adjust the parameter according to what you want.

The result for `16pt` is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabular*` environment. As you noted, it's not necessary to set the overall width to `1\textwidth`. Something like `0.55\textwidth` may be more appropriate.

Observe that it's possible to enliven the "look" of the table a bit by (a) giving more structure to the header and (b) adding a bit of whitespace after every fifth row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.75pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Estatísticas Descritivas -- Distribuição por UF} 
\begin{tabular*}{0.55\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    l *{3}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\toprule
  UF & {Controle} & {Tratado} & {Total} \\ 
     & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
  MG & 16.06 & 12.09 & 15.30 \\ 
  SP & 11.20 & 16.62 & 12.23 \\ 
  BA & 8.39 & 9.17 & 8.54 \\ 
  RS & 8.38 & 5.93 & 7.91 \\ 
  PR & 6.72 & 6.41 & 6.66 \\ \addlinespace % every 5th row
  GO & 4.33 & 4.01 & 4.27 \\ 
  SC & 3.97 & 4.85 & 4.14 \\ 
  PB & 4.44 & 2.02 & 3.98 \\ 
  MA & 4.06 & 3.54 & 3.96 \\ 
  PE & 3.91 & 3.21 & 3.78 \\ \addlinespace
  CE & 3.84 & 3.41 & 3.76 \\ 
  PI & 3.87 & 2.94 & 3.69 \\ 
  PA & 2.62 & 4.51 & 2.98 \\ 
  RN & 2.76 & 3.08 & 2.82 \\ 
  MT & 2.38 & 2.53 & 2.41 \\ \addlinespace
  RJ & 1.94 & 3.36 & 2.21 \\ 
  TO & 2.15 & 2.11 & 2.15 \\ 
  AL & 2.06 & 1.23 & 1.90 \\ 
  ES & 1.38 & 1.95 & 1.49 \\ 
  SE & 1.55 & 1.09 & 1.46 \\ \addlinespace
  MS & 1.31 & 1.88 & 1.42 \\ 
  AM & 1.03 & 2.22 & 1.26 \\ 
  RO & 0.84 & 0.97 & 0.87 \\ 
  AC & 0.36 & 0.22 & 0.33 \\ 
  AP & 0.25 & 0.33 & 0.27 \\ \addlinespace
  RR & 0.19 & 0.29 & 0.21 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of the `S` columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[vmargin=3cm, hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[group-separator={.},
            group-four-digits,
            output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\newcommand{\M}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}{c}}


\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\caption{Estatísticas Descritivas - Distribuição por UF}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.2, table-column-width=28mm]}@{}}
  \toprule

UF & {Controle (\%)} & {Tratado (\%)} & {Total (\%)} \\
  \midrule
MG & 16.06 & 12.09 & 15.30 \\
  SP & 11.20 & 16.62 & 12.23 \\
  BA & 8.39 & 9.17 & 8.54 \\
  RS & 8.38 & 5.93 & 7.91 \\
  PR & 6.72 & 6.41 & 6.66 \\
  GO & 4.33 & 4.01 & 4.27 \\
  SC & 3.97 & 4.85 & 4.14 \\
  PB & 4.44 & 2.02 & 3.98 \\
  MA & 4.06 & 3.54 & 3.96 \\
  PE & 3.91 & 3.21 & 3.78 \\
  CE & 3.84 & 3.41 & 3.76 \\
  PI & 3.87 & 2.94 & 3.69 \\
  PA & 2.62 & 4.51 & 2.98 \\
  RN & 2.76 & 3.08 & 2.82 \\
  MT & 2.38 & 2.53 & 2.41 \\
  RJ & 1.94 & 3.36 & 2.21 \\
  TO & 2.15 & 2.11 & 2.15 \\
  AL & 2.06 & 1.23 & 1.90 \\
  ES & 1.38 & 1.95 & 1.49 \\
  SE & 1.55 & 1.09 & 1.46 \\
  MS & 1.31 & 1.88 & 1.42 \\
  AM & 1.03 & 2.22 & 1.26 \\
  RO & 0.84 & 0.97 & 0.87 \\
  AC & 0.36 & 0.22 & 0.33 \\
  AP & 0.25 & 0.33 & 0.27 \\
  RR & 0.19 & 0.29 & 0.21 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]